# i do not understand the memory allocation of element in 2-D array using function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

first we declare pointer to pointer variable **matrix=NULL in main program .then we pass &matrix as argument in the function .in function it has parameter ex: void allocate(int ***pointer , int row  ,int column)now ,
i start to get confuse with pointer .as function has 3 astrik(*) so do i have to use (**pointer) or just (pointer) while allocating memory for the 2-D array .like below
**pointer= malloc(sizeof(int *)*row);
pointer =malloc(sizeof(int *)*rwo):
after this i have another issue :

somehow i get to understand that pointer= malloc(sizeof(int *)*row) is memory allocation for each row of the array but when it comes to allocation for each element i get confused more.because we declare (martrix)/(pointer in function ) as pointer to pointer right but when we do memory allocation for each element i see (pointer[i])/*(poinetr +i).

```
        for(int i = 0 ;i<row ; i++)
        {
         *(pointer +i)=malloc(sizeof(int)*column);
        }
```

as my understanding when any pointer is done increment (++) with 1 it increase the size and ultimetly forms a array  right. while here pointer being itself array of array (rows) then how.

*(pointer +i) is used to allocate the memory of the element in row . instead of forming a. array .

i am in complete confusion with pointer so please consider my question of even though make sense
thank you
here is my code:

Question:
Function to get input matrix combine with dynamic memory allocation
1 Function to calculate calculate matrix1 – matrix2 and store them to the third matrix and print out the result matrix .
1 Function to free the matrix of any size
(You have to create 3 function then using function call in the main to create the program and before read input matrix ask user to enter dimension for 2 input matrix)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void input( int ***pointer , int row , int column )
{
    pointer= malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
    for(int i = 0 ;i<row ; i++)
    {
        *(pointer + i)=malloc(sizeof(int )*column);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ;i<row ;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j <column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&pointer[i][j]); 
        }
    }


}
void calculate(int ***pointer1 ,int ***pointer2 , int row , int column )
{
    int **matrix3= malloc(sizeof(int *)*row);

    for(int i =0 ;i<row ; i++)
    {
        *(matrix3 +i)=malloc(sizeof(int)*column);
    }

    for(int i= 0 ;i<row ;i++)
    {
        for(int j= 0;j <column; j++)
        {
            matrix3[i][j]=pointer1[i][j]-pointer2[i][j];
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0 ; i<row ;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ;j<column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",matrix3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<row ;i++)
    {
        free(*(matrix3 +i));


    }
    free(matrix3);

}

void frem(int ***pointer1,int row )
{
    for(int i =0 ;i<row ;i++)
    {
        free(*(pointer1 +i));
    }
    free(pointer1);
}

int main ()
{
    int row , column ; 
    scanf("%d%d",&row , &column);

    int **matrix1= NULL ,**matrix2 =NULL ;
    input(&matrix1,row , column );
    input(&matrix2, row , column);
    calculate(&matrix1 , &matrix2 , row , column);
    frem(&matrix1, row );
    frem(&matrix2, row );
    return 0 ;
}
```

while i run the code it says

```
 format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   16 |             scanf("%d",&pointer[i][j]);
      |                    ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     |  |
      |                     |  int **
      |                     int *
```

Comment: This **isn't a 2D array**. It's a pointer to a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays of ints.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why you would ever use the evil-looking `int***` is when you return a pointer-to-pointer through a parameter. Your function `input` is all wrong.

- `pointer= malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);` is wrong, you should assign a pointer-to-pointer to where `pointer` points at: `*pointer = malloc...`.
- `*(pointer + i)` First of all, this style is pretty much always wrong since it is just a less readable version of `pointer[i]`. However, that would be wrong too, since we need to assign each pointer previously allocated to point at an array. That would be `(*pointer)[i] = ...`
- Similarly, `scanf("%d",&pointer[i][j]);` should be `&((*pointer)[i][j])`.

We could have avoided all this mess if we had done `int** tmp` then done all malloc on that variable, and then at the very end of the function `*pointer = tmp;`.

The function `calculate` similarly does not make any sense. You don't need 3 levels of indirection at all there. Nor do you need a local array to hold the results.

More importantly: ***this whole way of allocating 2D arrays in intrinsically wrong to begin with!*** It might have made sense for arrays of strings, so called "jagged arrays". But it doesn't make any sense whatsoever for a 2D matrix. Detailed explanation regarding why your teacher/book is teaching you the wrong things here: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). Please share with the would-be teacher/author...

A simplified, somewhat beginner-friendly version of parts of your code might look like this:

```
void* get_2D_matrix (int row, int col)
{
    // allocate an actual 2D array:
    int (*matrix)[col] = malloc( sizeof(int[row][col]) );
    if(matrix == NULL)
    {
      /* error handling */
    }

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}


int main ()
{
    int row=3, col=2; 

    int (*matrix1)[col] = get_2D_matrix(row, col) ;
    ...

        do_something(matrix1[i][j]);

    ...

    free(matrix); // just one call required.
```